# How do I use the iphone camera and keyboard to build a photo journal that can be stored on the iphone and later printed?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need some guidance on how to approach this problem. Goal:

1. The user takes a photo with the iphone camera.
2. Adds some text about the photo location, date taken, photo
   description, etc.
3. The photo and text is then stored together in a file on the iPhone.
4. The user can add more photos and text to the same file and
   eventually printed out the   file as a photo journal.

   Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've begun to read about the elements, but don't see exactly how to pull them all together into a nice package.  I'm using `Xcode 4.6.2` and Storyboards.  Hard to believe this type of codes doesn't already exist.  If it does, I'd greatly appreciate being directed to it.

Comment: Here is some guidance:  Use the search feature on this site!  You could accomplish what you're asking with a search for each one of the items you've listed in your question.

Comment: Here are some links to get you started.. **1:** http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html .. **2 & 3:** https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html .. **4:** http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/Printing/Printing.html

Comment: Thank you.  I've used those resources to build a test app that takes pictures and browses photo libraries.  All of the examples used IB (.xib) to build their code.  The app that I want to incorporate this into uses storyboards.  When I rebuild the .xib example with storyboards, I keep getting errors associated with using kUTTypeImage and KUTTypeMove. The errors are that these are "undefined symbols for architecture i386" and "Linker command failed with exit Code 1".  Two questions:

Comment: Sorry..hit the return key accidentally.  Two questions: (1) do I need to do this .xib to storyboard conversion, or can I incorporate the .xib camera/photo browser test app into my largely storyboard develop larger app, and (2) if not, any clue on how to address these error messages associated with the kUTType?  Not sure what the "Linker command..." error is all about.